# jQuery load a script after an action has happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I am creating an intro page to my site, the first 5 seconds shows `<div class="splash_container">` then after 5 seconds I want to show `<div class="canvas_container">`

I have managed to do this by hiding the second div with css then showing them using the following jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.splash_container').delay(5000).fadeOut();
    jQuery('.canvas_container').delay(5500).fadeIn();

});
```

The problem I have is that `.canvas_container` contains a html5 canvas animation that I created which needs to start when the div is visible - at the minute, it starts on page load, so by the time it shows it is 5500ms into the animation.

Is there a way to delay the loading of the script for my canvas animation?

Here is the script for my canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var counter = 0;
    var completeCycle = [0];
    var leftColumn = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"];
    var rightColumn = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"];


    var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var b = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
    newOrder();
    loop();


function loop() {
if (counter > completeCycle.length) {
    counter = 1;
    newOrder();
    //console.log(completeCycle);
    setTimeout(function() {
        context.clearRect(50, 0, 180, 400); // clears the animation
        setTimeout(loop, 200);   // start it up again
    }, 5000);     // but wait a second
} else {
    drawLine(counter,context);
    counter++;
    setTimeout(loop, 100);

}
}  // start the loop immediately



    function newOrder()
    {
        a = shuffleUp(a);
        b = shuffleUp(b);

        //complete array, just because I can:
        completeCycle = [0];
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            completeCycle.push((b[i] * 2)+1);
            completeCycle.push(a[i]*2);
        }
        completeCycle.push((b[6]* 2)+1);
        //console.log(b);
        console.log(completeCycle);


    }


    //This function uses the "Fisher-Yates shuffle"
    //More information about this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
    function shuffleUp(array)
    {
        var m = array.length, t, i;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle…
        while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
        }

        return array;
    }

    function moveToPos(whichOne, context) {
        //Change the '5 +' to offset more/less from top.

        var yLoc = (whichOne % 2 == 0) ?
            5 + (whichOne / 2) * 30 :
            5 + ((whichOne - 1) / 2) * 30;

        context.moveTo(
            (whichOne % 2 == 0) ? 55 : 220
            ,yLoc);//,2 + (whichOne / 2) * 30);
    }

    function drawToPos(whichOne, context) {
        //Change the '5 +' to offset more/less from top.
        var yLoc = (whichOne % 2 == 0) ?
            5 + (whichOne / 2) * 30 :
            5 + ((whichOne - 1) / 2) * 30;


        context.lineTo(
            (whichOne % 2 == 0) ? 55 : 220
            ,yLoc);//, 2 + ((whichOne) / 2) * 30);
    }


    function drawLine(counter, context) {

        context.beginPath();

        //Move to the last point position...
        moveToPos(completeCycle[counter - 1],context);
        drawToPos(completeCycle[counter], context);
        //console.log(completeCycle);
        // Stroke Style
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
        context.lineCap = 'round';
        context.stroke();
    }


        // Create words
        // LEFT WORDS
        context.font = 'normal 12px Menlo';
        context.fillStyle = 'white';


        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            context.fillText(leftColumn[i], 0, 10 + (i*30));
            context.fillText(rightColumn[i], 240, 10 + (i*30));
        }
```

The script is added inline with the div (i.e. not loaded as an external resource).

Comment: have you tried `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: Move the "working" part of your script into a function and call that on completion of the animation. Your scripts should be assumed to be preloaded, so it is about *when* to run the specific lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is written to "run on load". If the starting time of an operation is critical you should never depend on the script load time.

Change that script to be a library of functions (that get started externally). e.g. Put this part of your code in another function:

```
// Global vars outside all functions
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var counter = 0;
var completeCycle = [0];
var leftColumn = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"];
var rightColumn = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"];
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var b = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

function startup(){
    newOrder();
    loop();
}
```

and call on completion of the animation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.splash_container').delay(5000).fadeOut();
    jQuery('.canvas_container').delay(5500).fadeIn(startup);

});
```

Your script then just gets loaded, up-front, like any other library.

Comment: thanks for this, definetly see what you're saying, however it's not working on my site. I'm getting an error in the console saying "context is undefined" - does the whole of my canvas script need to be loaded in the startup function do you think?

Comment: @Sam Skirrow: Apologies, those vars should be outside the function. I will edit. :)

Comment: Spot on, works great and makes a lot of sense. Thanks.